# Экранирование экранированной строки в методе GET Web-Api контроллера

Tags: c#, строки, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net

У меня есть контроллер,который принимает строку в качестве аргумента:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get(string str)
    {
        ////
    }
```

я передаю в него строку с экранированными кавычками: `010352870230181421N6e=qV*9\"'M/t`
в итоге внутри контроллера получаю строку: `010352870230181421N6e=qV*9\\\"'M/t`

Хотелось бы изменить это поведение, так, чтобы строка оставалась в прежнем состоянии. Или хотя-бы использовать какой-то метод из коробки, чтобы вернуть ее в прежнее состоянии.
Дело в том, что Replace тут тоже не работает.

Comment: А зачем вы экранируете кавычки? Очевидно же ваша строка еще раз где-то заэкранировалась. То есть, это дважды экранированная строка. Следовательно, вам нужно дважды ее разэкранировать.

Comment: А вы уверены, что строка и правда дважды экранируется, или это только отладчик вам так отображает?

Comment: Строка экранируется дважды, потому что я потом ее сравниваю с исходной, которая берется из другого источника

Comment: Если источник присылает неправильную строку, имеет смысл исправить источник, а не подгонять сервер под баги клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта строка дважды экранирована, ее можно дважды разэкранировать.

Способов много, вот один из них

```cs
str = Regex.Unescape(Regex.Unescape(str));
```

Получится

```
010352870230181421N6e=qV*9"'M/t
```

Или так попробовать

```cs
public string Unescape(string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++);
    {
        if (text[i] == '\\' && i < text.Length - 1)
            sb.Append(text[++i]);
        else
            sb.Append(text[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло! Если не трудно опишите другие способы, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vasiliy с ходу таких не покажу, например удалять бэкслеш, пропуская следующий символ после него. Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его принятым. Галочка слева от ответа.